# 3000 forgotten Halachot - out of how many?

Tags: halacha-theory, mishna, maseches-temura

The Mishnah we have counts around 4200. THe Gemmorah in Temura 16a says:

> שלשת אלפים הלכות נשתכחו בימי אבלו של משה
>
> three thousand halachot were forgotten during the period of mourning for Moses

The number is very exact so it looks like they counted the Halachot. So how many were there in the first place?

Comment: Looks like a pretty round number to me.

Comment: [Chagigah 14a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=13&daf=14&format=pdf) says: "קילל ישעיה את ישראל ולא נתקררה דעתו עד שאמר להם ... דכתיב _כי הנה האדון ה' צבאות מסיר מירושלם ומיהודה משען ומשענה_ ... _משענה_ אלו בעלי משנה כגון ר"י בן תימא וחביריו פליגו בה רב פפא ורבנן חד אמר **שש מאות סדרי משנה** וחד אמר **שבע מאות סדרי משנה**".

Comment: @TamirEvan Is it anything real? Does it have cross-reference with other statements elsewhere?

Comment: Maybe they knew the count once they were restored? Seems more farfetched that they had a total number and figured out how many were missing...